# Make MEDIA_ROOT point to a website url instead of a local directory

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, static-files

So i have two Django projects, a main and a child-site, both are running on separate servers with separate domain-names. The media files are stored on and can only be posted to the main site, but the child-site has to access those media files somehow.

How can i configure the MEDIA_ROOT setting (or something else, for that matter, in my project) so that the media files are automatically fetched from my main site. Or what changes can i make so that a fixed URL (of my main site) is added as a prefix when addressing any sort of media file.

P.S. i am using pythonanywhere (two beginner/free accts., one for each site).

Comment: Here is a guide on how to serve images from Amazon S3: https://medium.com/the-geospatials/serve-django-static-media-files-on-aws-s3-part-2-d0e8578dd2db

You can adapt it to serve images from your domain instead of Amazon's S3 domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply ignore `MEDIA_ROOT` and set `MEDIA_URL`. `MEDIA_ROOT` is used to fetch resources where `MEDIA_URL` is used to build the url.

@see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_URL

Please read the difference between `MEDIA_` and `STATIC_`. MEDIA is for user-uploaded files.

More at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: Yep, i commented out MEDIA_ROOT, and simply provided the MEDIA_URL of my main site's media dir. Worked straightaway.. Thanks a great deal. I was just stuck thinking that the MEDIA_ROOT is somehow necessary in identifying the actual location, and that the MEDIA_URL just tells what you want to show your users as the media url - but i guess that's not how that works. Thanks again.